# React Hooks: Getting data in "location" but not in params with "Link"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I am trying to pass params/data by url from one page to another page with link below is the code for passing the data.

```
 {Array.isArray(products) ?
      products.map((product, i) =>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{i + 1}</td>
            <Link to={`/campaing/${product._id}`}>
              <td>{product.name}</td>
            </Link>
            <td>Rs: {product.price}</td>
            <td>{product.rating}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      ) : <h3>No Product Present Add One</h3>
    }
```

and in app all routers are present

```
 <PrivateRoute path="/user" component={BoardUser} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/campaing/:id" exact component={Campaings} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/mod" component={BoardModerator} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/admin" component={BoardAdmin} />
```

In campaig router

```
const {id} = useParams();
  console.log(id + ' -------------------'); //undefined
  
  console.log(props.location.pathname) //campaing/21ye7wqdg3276e
```

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: Please share the full code to understand more well specially `App.js` the file you placed your routes.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem  just neede to get computedMatch also as its just passing location and data from body by props.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, computedMatch: match }) => {
const isLoggedIn = JWTDATA();
console.log(match);
return (
    <Route {...match}
        render={props =>
            isLoggedIn ? (
                <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
                <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
            )
        }
    />
)
```

}